# htaccess removing .php extension and pretty urls

Tags: regex, .htaccess

Im trying to both remove .php extensions. So for example "http://localhost/timetable/login" instead of "http://localhost/timetable/login.php"

But also have

"http://localhost/timetable/38/" instead of 
"http://localhost/timetable/index.php?week=38"

Im able to get one or the other working but not both at the same time. Im assuming its because there is a conflict between them but Im not advanced enough to find it.

Here is my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)$ index.php?week=$2 
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/$ index.php?week=$2
```

If in the address bar I type "http://localhost/timetable/38" it brings me to "http://localhost/38/" and an Object not Found error.

Does anyone know what the problem is ?

***UPDATE:*** I can now go to the page but

```
echo $_GET['week'];
```

Is returning empty result, so its ignroing the 40 in "http://localhost/timetable/40"

Comment: Sounds very strange and cannot be explained by the rules you posted. There must be other rewriting rules in place. Please add those to the question.

Comment: Simply remove the penultimate line of your file and replace the final line with:

Comment: @arkascha There are no other rules that's the whole document.

Comment: @Martin I tried however it didn't help.

Comment: Did you clear your cache and try a new connection to the site? That was quick...

Comment: @Martin thank you I'm not getting that error anymore, however is it possible now that $_GET['week']; doesn't work? Because if I go to "http://localhost/timetable/index.php?week=40" My page is working as intended however if I go to "http://localhost/timetable/40" It brings me to my page but its like it doesnt get the number 40 like it should.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180892/discussion-between-user2989367-and-martin).

Comment: It should be $1 and not $2 I believe. Try: `RewriteRule ([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?week=$1 [QSA,L]`

Answer (score 0):

You only have one capture group when you try to get the week. So it should be $1 instead of $2.

According to [this test tool](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be), the following should work:

```
RewriteRule ([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?week=$1
```

I would do something like this:

```
# rewrite if url ends with a number and possibly a slash
RewriteRule ([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?week=$1 [QSA,L] 

# do not append .php if it already ends with .php, other add .php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.php$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Im getting the error "The requested URL /38 was not found on this server."

Comment: Also if you only use `RewriteRule ([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?week=$1` without the RewriteCond before it? It may not work, I removed it from the answer.

Comment: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.php$ # do not append .php if it already ends with .php is causing Internal Server Error

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. the comments behind the rules must be removed. And please check if the main question is answered. Does it work with $1 instead of $2?

Comment: Yes it does on localhost, not on my server however, but Ive run into another issue where my server isnt reading my .htaccess file while in the same directory as my website, therefore Im trying to fix that issue now.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using separate rewrite rule for each input, you should consider routing all of them as a single string to some php file.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

In you php file, you can then separate the string as input and use them as required.

```
<?php
$inputs = explode('/', $_GET['page']);
```